# Degree after BSc in Computer Science: Marketing, MBA, Techno-MBA, HCI?

Tags: education

Since a year I am a graduated Computer Engineer, and am now working in named field since 2 years. However, I'd like to get a Masters in a "softer" field and was thinking over the following choices:

- **MBA**: Master of Business Administration, to bridge the business world with the world of computer science. Would give me an interesting job, travel potential, high salary etc.
- **Techno-MBA**: Sort of an MBA, but aimed at people who already have a degree in Computer Science.
- **HCI**: Human Computer Interaction degree, something I have been **very** interested in, but feel like it doesn't have the growth potential of MBA/Techno-MBA
- **Marketing**: My most recent brainchild is a degree in Marketing, is this at all a good idea given my background? Growth potential?

Main priority: Gaining a skill, and gaining a job allowing me to use my social skills. Which path has the best "career potential"? (Controversial I know)

Any thoughts? Any feedback welcome.

Edit: DOH. Realized that the first sentence makes no sense. Was running my own semi-successful business during last year of school.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing everything I do now, I'd go for an MBA.

I studied Software Engineering at university and we spent a tremendous amount of time on esoteric things that we really interesting but I've never used. Technology has moved on, but each new thing can be learned, usually on-the-job.

Conversely, it is quite difficult to learn business skills while doing a software engineering job. Taking time out specifically to follow an MBA would give you the breathing space to be able to absorb the important concepts properly. The nature of businesses may evolve (international, online-only, etc) but generally it doesn't move that fast, so what you learn in an MBA will be relevant for some time to come.

If you need more evidence, look up what educational background big CEO/CTO's have in our industry.

Comment: +1, I don't think that an MBA necessarily translates to business skills, but many companies look for one for upper management.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with what you say, that business skills can be hard to acquire on the job, but the same must go for marketing, no? Maybe marketing/computer science is not a very potent combination.

Answer (score 5):

Answer this question: "What do I want to be when I grow up?"

If you can honestly answer that question, your choice will be made for you.  Any job is only as good as long as something about it makes you happy, and that's not always (and rarely primarily) money.

Comment: Would you say it's easy, or difficult, to choose which field to pursue if you have no hands on experience of the field in question?

Comment: If you have nothing of value to add, refrain from answering.

Comment: Depends on how strongly you can answer the question.  If you can say "I've always wanted to be a ____" you can pursue that with a passion.  If you say "I *think* I want to _____" then you can do a little research into the field, and make a choice.  If you are truly undecided, you may want to get some experience in one or more of them, and then decide.  Kind of like renting an apartment for a few years before buying your first house - you learn what you need, what you like, what you don't like, etc.

Comment: You asked, as you say, a "(Controversial I know)" question, and then criticize an answer?  An answer that has been upvoted, by the way?  And one that you asked a follow-up question on?

Comment: Would you be satisfied with an answer that provides no information? I am not. The question is vague, yes, because I thought I could use this forum as part of my research process. Apparently that might prove difficult since people like yourself like to dwell here.

Comment: I will withdraw my answer when people are done upvoting it.  Look for lots of answers from "people like me" that "dwell here."  I'm sure criticizing those that attempt to help is the best course.

Comment: "Would you say it's easy, or difficult, to choose which field to pursue if you have no hands on experience of the field in question?". Would you say it's easy, or difficult, to choose FOR YOU which field you'll excel at?

Comment: Mike: Yes, I would say that it is rather hard. There's an entire field of work dedicated at answering these questions: Student counselors. Do you think it's easy? I am looking for some fresh insights, not to cause trouble.